# Detecting NSKeyUp of the Shift key

Tags: macos, cocoa, keystroke

I am using this to detect keystrokes on my app...

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskKeyDown
                                    handler:^NSEvent * (NSEvent * theEvent)
```

OK I can use `theEvent` to know what characters were typed and know if a shift was pressed using this:

```
NSString *typedKey = theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers;
BOOL shiftDetected = [theEvent modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask;
```

My App has an interface displayed with some buttons and I am allowing the keyboard to be used instead of clicking on the buttons. This interface has 3 buttons in particular that has a second function.

For example: the first button has 2 functions, `A` and `B` but just the `A` label is displayed on that button. Lets say I specify that the letter `Q` is the keyboard shortcut for that button. If the user presses `Q` function `A` is executed. If the user presses `Shift Q` then function `B` is executed.

But this is the problem. I need to detect all presses or releases of the `Shift`, because the moment the user presses `Shift` I have to change the label of that button from `A` to `B`, so the user knows that now that button will lead to the execution of function `B` instead of `A`.  Like a keyboard that will change from lowercase to uppercase while `Shift` is being hold and change back to lowercase the moment `Shift` is released.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a simple project using `addLocalMonitorForEvents` function. Please check my code, it is Swift code but I think it should be as same as objective c.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.flagsChanged, .keyDown]) { (theEvent) -> NSEvent? in
        if theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.shift) {
            if theEvent.keyCode == 56 { // this is Shif key
                print("Shift START!")
            }
            else {
                print("Shift pressed with keycode \(theEvent.keyCode)")
            }
        }
        else {
            if theEvent.keyCode == 56 { // this is Shif key
                print("Shift END!")
            }
            else {
                print("Normal keycode \(theEvent.keyCode)")
            }
        }
        return theEvent
    }
}
```

This is Objective c:

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskFlagsChanged|NSEventMaskKeyDown handler:^NSEvent * (NSEvent * theEvent) {
    if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagShift) {
        if (theEvent.keyCode == 56) { // this is Shif key
            NSLog(@"Shift START");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Shift pressed with keycode %d", theEvent.keyCode);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (theEvent.keyCode == 56) { // this is Shif key
            NSLog(@"Shift END");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Normal keycode %d", theEvent.keyCode);
        }
    }

    return theEvent;
}];
```

Just copy and paste this part to your `AppDelegate` for quick testing.

[image]

Comment: I have tried to convert your first like to `Objective C` and it is crashing with the message `Invalid message sent to event NSEvent type:flagschanges... keycode=56`... the code is this `[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskKeyDown  | NSEventMaskFlagsChanged handler...`

Comment: @SpaceDog Use "|" to use multiple masks. Check my objective c code.